# ¿Como saber que número de id es el siguiente en un campo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT?

Tags: android, sqlite

Hola amigos quisiera que me echen una mano como puedo saber que numero de id es el siguiente de un campo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT SQLite, en Android.

> Supongamos que he eliminado a deis registros que tenia en mi BD, entonces el siguiente id es el **11**, me gustaría que me ayuden con ese problema, de como obtener el siguiente valor id.

Comment: Eso va a depender del contexto, por ejemplo, si estás insertando en ese momento y la consulta tiene éxito, podrás obtener el último id insertado con [`last_insert_rowid`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html), ahora bien, si la consulta de inserción falla, te devolverá `cero (0)`, por eso digo que depende del contexto.

Comment: Excelente por la respuesta pero lo logre con la siguiente sentencia `SELECT MAX(_id) FROM NAME_TABLE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Depende del contexto

#### Si estás insertando y la consulta tiene éxito

Si estás insertando en ese momento y la consulta tiene éxito, podrás obtener el último id insertado con [`last_insert_rowid`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html), ahora bien, si la consulta de inserción falla, te devolverá cero (0).

Eso significa que antes de usarlo, deberías controlar tu código para asegurar que la consulta se realizó correctamente.

---

#### Si estás en un `SELECT` normal:

```
SELECT MAX(id) 
    FROM  tu-tabla;
```

O bien:

```
SELECT id 
    FROM  tu-tabla
    WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id)  FROM tu-tabla);
```

O también:

```
SELECT id FROM tu-tabla ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```